# Python Geo-Spatial Coordinate Format Conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, gis, latitude-longitude

I have a dataframe containing 6 columns of coordinate pairs:

```
Degrees|Minutes|Seconds
```

(for both latitude and longitude). This is known as the *NAD83 format*.

I want to convert these into a new dataframe of only 2 columns in decimal format, known as *NAD27*.

The library I typically use, geopy supports virtually every format, so there actually isn't a dedicated conversion function. I went through the documentation here to be sure:
https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.0/

Does python have any other means to convert to NAD27?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do NAD83->NAD27 transformations or just wish to convert DMS to a decimal representation? A datum (NAD) does specify the way the coordinates should be represented (that is, either decimal or DMS).

Comment: Also, are you certain that the NAD83 or NAD27 datum is the one you want to use? A more typical choice would be WGS84, the one used by GPS.

Comment: I'm 80% sure I need NAD27, I have to check through a few other libraries to see what they accept. So far it seems NAD27 is the way to go.

Comment: Perhaps no longer so easily done, but please include a few samples in your question! The D M S format can easily make mistakes with recording the compass direction sign (E vs W, N vs S) from to value when you near the equator or the zeroth meridian (e.g. -0 42 17 is readily interpreted as having no sign at all)!  To compensate, sometimes the sign is added to all three columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's suppose your DataFrame `df` contains columns `lonD`, `lonM`, `lonS`, `latD`, `latM` and `latS`.
Then the following should work, using `geopandas`, `shapely` and `pyproj` internally.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Point

def dms_to_dec(d, m, s):
    sign = 1 - 2 * np.signbit(d)
    return d + sign * m / 60 + sign * s / 3600
    
points = df.apply(lambda row: Point(dms_to_dec(*row[['lonD', 'lonM', 'lonS']]), 
                                    dms_to_dec(*row[['latD', 'latM', 'latS']])),
                  axis=1)
gdf_nad83 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=points, crs={'init': 'EPSG:4269'})
gdf_nad27 = gdf_nad83.to_crs({'init': 'EPSG:4267'})
```

Comment: Wow a conversion from scratch, you make it look easy! Thank you, let me try it out.

Comment: I keep getting errors when trying to install shapely via pip. It's very strange. I will see about locating a .whl file and installing that way.

Comment: Teah, shapely and gdal/ogr are definitely not the most convenient packages to set up. Using Anaconda usually makes it a lot easier, I recommend trying that out.

Comment: I actually do have anaconda, I'm running Python 3.5 on it, but it must not have come with the shapely library. Unfortunately, I'm limited to this version while I'm at work. I tried for a few days to download it while at work but to no avail. I really appreciate your answer, if it wasn't for this unforeseen complication I would have accepted it already. In light of all of this, would it be feasible to use numpy only? ( I have numpy at least). It would seem that the `Point` function has some extensive linear algebra going on. I probably couldn't figure it out by myself.

Comment: I tried writing my own function in numpy only, but I couldn't find any good resources. Googling 'how to convert coordinates' will display virtually only online converting tools, no tutorials.

Comment: Shapely uses proj4/pyproj internally, so you can try using it directly instead. I unfortunately can't help you any further right now since I'm on a vacation.

Comment: You can also try adding conda-forge to your conda channels, they have better support for geographic libs than the default channel.

Comment: I just not got it to work, your help was invaluable!

Comment: This should really be vectorised; I've added an answer that includes benchmarks.

Comment: You also have a bug: `np.sign()` can return `0.0`.. This causes any `0 degrees, (m) minutes, (s) seconds` value to become `0.0`, dropping the minutes and seconds altogether. This clips all points close to the equator to the equator, all points close to the zero-th meridian to the meridian.

Answer (score 4):

Because I ran into this too, and found the `df.apply()` approach too slow, I switched to using a `MultiPoint()` object and used vectorised operations, then turning that single object into `Point()`s with `list()`.

Moreover, we need to account for the fact that DMS columns may only have included the `-` sign on the D column. If that's the case and you are lucky the DataFrame was created using numpy floats, then `"-0.0"` has probably been stored as `numpy.NZERO` (negative zero), in which case we can still recover the sign using [`numpy.signbit()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.signbit.html). If not, the sign might be lost and points just south of the equator or west of the zero-th meridian will appear as just north or east instead.

Just to be explicit: the D, M, S coordinate notation is just that, a different way to note latitude and longitude coordinates, where D, M, and S stand for *degrees*, (arc) *minutes* and (arc) *seconds*. The decimal is another, which combines the degrees value with the arc minutes and arc seconds into a single number; an arc minute is 1/60th of a degree, and an arc second is 1/3600th of a degree, so you can do a little math to sum the values together (preserving the sign of the degree). GeoPy wants to work with decimal values, so you do need to fold the arc-seconds and arc-minutes into the degrees value.

On the other hand, NAD83 and NAD27 are not  [*geodetic datums* or *geodetic systems*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_datum), and such systems are notation agnostic. They are simply a standardised way of specifying what coordinate system to use and what point of reference the coordinate system is anchored to.

That said, geopandas *can* be used to transform between different geodetic datums. The project accepts [CRS strings](http://geopandas.org/projections.html) to define what coordinate system to use when interpreting points (of which the geodetic datum is a component); using a coordinate system database such as https://spatialreference.org/ to find the EPSG codes for NAD83 and NAD27, gives us [`EPSG:4269`](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4269/) and [`EPSG:4267`](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4267/), respectively. Note that you don't have to create a dataframe here, a `GeoSeries` is enough if all you want is *conversion*.

So, given that you have degrees, minutes and seconds, you need to convert those values to decimal coordinates to feed to geopandas. And you'd want to do this *fast and efficiently*. You can do this by using vectorised calculations (where numpy applies calculations to all rows using very fast arythmatic operations directly on the machine representation of the data, and not on the Python reprentations).

I'm sticking to the same convention here, input is a Pandas DataFrame `df` that contains columns `lonD`, `lonM`, `lonS`, `latD`, `latM` and `latS`. Using `geopandas`, `numpy` and `shapely`:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import asMultiPoint

def vec_dms_to_dec(d, m, s):
    """convert d, m, s coordinates to decimals

    Can be used as a vectorised operation on whole numpy arrays,
    each array must have the same shape.

    Handles signs only present on the D column, transparently.
    Note that for -0d Mm Ss inputs, the sign might be have been lost!
    However, if it was preserved as np.NZERO, this function will
    recover it with np.signbit().

    """
    assert d.shape == m.shape == s.shape
    # account for signs only present on d
    if (m >= 0).all() and (s >= 0).all():
        # all s and m values are without signs
        # so only d carries this info. Use the sign *bit* so negative
        # and positive zero are distinguished correctly.
        sign = np.where(np.signbit(d), np.ones_like(d) * -1.0, np.ones_like(d))
    else:
        sign = np.ones_like(d)
    return d + sign * m / 60 + sign * s / 3600

# Generate the column names, grouped by component
comps = ([f"{c}{a}" for c in ("lon", "lat")] for a in 'DMS')

# Create a single MultiPoint object from the vectorised conversions of the
# longitude and latitude columns
mpoint = asMultiPoint(
    vec_dms_to_dec(*(df[c].values for c in cols))
)

# Create a GeoSeries object from the MultiPoints object. Using `list()`
# produces `Point()` objects efficiently, faster than GeoSeries would
# otherwise.
# Interpret the points as using NAD83 == EPSG:4269
coords_nad83 = gpd.GeoSeries(list(mpoint), crs={'init': 'EPSG:4269'})

# Convert the series to NAD27 == EPSG:4267
coords_nad4267 = coords_nad83.to_crs(epsg=4267)
```

You are then free to convert those back again to values in D, M, S notation:

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint

def geoseries_to_dms(s, all_signed=True):
    fractions, decimals = np.modf(np.array(MultiPoint(s.to_list())))
    if not all_signed:
        # only the d values signed. Looses information
        # for input values in the open range (-1.0, 0.0)
        fractions = np.abs(fractions)
    fractions, minutes = np.modf(fractions * 60)
    seconds = fractions * 60
    return pd.DataFrame(
        data=np.stack(
            (decimals, minutes, seconds), axis=2
        ).reshape(-1, 6),
        columns=loncols + latcols
    )
```

The above uses [`np.modf()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.modf.html) to split out the decimal portion from the fraction, after which the absolute value of the fraction can be split out into arc minutes and arc seconds again.

If you still wanted to use a `GeoDataFrame`, create one from the converted `GeoSeries`, or just create one from the `MultiPoints()` object the same way you create a `GeoSeries` from a `MultiPoints()` object, by using `GeoDataFrame(..., geometry=list(points), ...)`.

#### Benchmarking, or why you'd want vectorisation

On vectorisation: My code above takes each of the degrees, minutes and seconds columns as three separate numpy arrays and uses those 3 arrays to create a single array of decimal degree values, *in one step across all rows*. There is no need for a separate call for just the latitude or just the longitude values, as numpy processes `d`, `m` and `s` as arrays, and doesn't care if they have just one dimension or 15.

This translates to vastly faster execution. To benchmark this, lets create a new dataframe with an arbitrary number of dms coordinates; I found it easier to just generate decimal values and convert these to dms values:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point, asMultiPoint

def random_world_coords(n):
    coords = np.random.random((2, n))
    coords[0] = coords[0] * 180 - 90  # lat between -90, 90
    coords[1] = coords[1] * 360 - 180 # lon between -180, 180
    # convert to d, m, s
    fractions, decimals = np.modf(coords)
    fractions, minutes = np.modf(fractions * 60)
    seconds = fractions * 60
    return pd.DataFrame(
        data=np.stack((decimals, minutes, seconds), axis=2).reshape(-1, 6),
        columns=["lonD", "lonM", "lonS", "latD", "latM", "latS"]
    )
```

and define the approaches to convert these values to decimal points, suitable for `GeoSeries()` consumption, as functions. I removed the sign handling as the random data included signs on all dms columns, which then also makes it trivial to use the same conversion function for both scalar and array operations:

```
def dms_to_dec(d, m, s):
    """convert d, m, s coordinates to decimals"""
    return d + m / 60 + s / 3600

def martinvalgur_apply(df):
    return df.apply(
        lambda row: Point(
            dms_to_dec(*row[['lonD', 'lonM', 'lonS']]), 
            dms_to_dec(*row[['latD', 'latM', 'latS']])
        ),
        axis=1
    )

def martijnpieters_vectorised(df):
    comps = ([f"{c}{a}" for c in ("lon", "lat")] for a in 'DMS')
    return list(asMultiPoint(
        dms_to_dec(*(df[c].values for c in comps))
    ))
```

at which point you can test how fast either on is with IPython's `%timeit` or another benchmarking library:

```
df100 = random_world_coords(100)
%timeit martinvalgur_apply(df100)
%timeit martijnpieters_vectorised(df100)
# 433 ms ± 15.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
# 96.2 ms ± 7.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

That's 100 items, and vectorising is about 4.5 times faster.

If you increase the count to 1000 the numbers the difference becomes much more apparent:

```
df1000 = random_world_coords(1000)
%timeit martinvalgur_apply(df1000)
%timeit martijnpieters_vectorised(df1000)
# 4.31 s ± 111 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
# 35.7 ms ± 909 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

So at 1000 rows, vectorising takes mere milliseconds still and is taking *less* time because we are now hitting optimisations used for larger datasets, but using the time taken to run `df.apply()` on those 1000 rows has ballooned to over 4 seconds.

(Note: I also ran the tests with a deepcopy of the input for each test created with `DataFrame.copy()` to make sure that I wasn't gaining advantages of already-processed data, but the timings still went down, not up, for the 100 -> 1000 rows case).

The non-vectorised version takes time directly proportional to the number of rows, so the numbers for 10k rows are predictable:

```
df10k = random_world_coords(10_000)
%timeit martinvalgur_apply(df10k)
%timeit martijnpieters_vectorised(df10k)
# 44.1 s ± 1.1 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
# 331 ms ± 14.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

That the `df.apply()` version took 44 seconds was expected, but I did have to wait a full 5 minutes for the result to come in as IPython still runs the test 7 times.

The vectorised approach clocked in at a mere 331ms, so we can test *just* that version at 1 million rows:

```
df1m = random_world_coords(1_000_000)
%timeit martijnpieters_vectorised(df1m)
# 3.18 s ± 114 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So the vectorised approach scales linearly as well, but it started from a far lower value. Most of this time goes into creating the list of `Point()` objects from the `MultiPoint()` object, something the geopandas project could improve on by [supporting Shapely `GeometrySequence` objects natively](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1037).

Comment: You raise a good point regarding the near-zero degree values. There is still the issue of representing negative near-zero values with this approach, though. E.g. -0°30' and 0°30' will both get mapped to 0.5°. This can only really be resolved by storing the sign in a separate column or using a somewhat weird convention of storing minutes and seconds as negative in such cases.

Comment: @MartinValgur: indeed, that hadn’t even occurred to me. I have a CSV with lon / lat coordinates recorded for the ISS with dms columns that had dropped all the signs so I did not run into that issue. I was able to add back the signs purely by looking at the delta changes (the ISS doesn’t change direction luckily).  I’ll point that out to the author of the data as well.

Comment: @MartinValgur and thinking some more, there probably was meant to be a separate sign column that got dropped, rather than that the signs were removed from the dms columns. I am pretty certain now that the data was generated using pyephem so I can easily recover the signs by recalculating the ISS positions for the dates recorded.

Comment: @MartinValgur I note that [`skyfield`’s `Angle` class](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/api-units.html#skyfield.units.Angle) sets all three components to use the same sign when you ask it for dms values. In which case you’d *not* want to correct for the sign on d!

Comment: @MartinValgur: I found [`np.signbit()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.signbit.html) today, and it captures exactly what we need here: if the sign bit has been set. If your data has negative zeros in the d column, then `np.signbit()` will produce `True` for those values, and `False` for positive zeros.