# Efficient way to find which row a pair of GPS coordinates belong to

Tags: python, pandas, geo

I have a dataframe (Call it A) with a set of GPS lat/long coordinates

```
Lat | Long
28.6752213, 77.09311140000001
```

I have another CSV (with many rows, over a million - call it B) of the form
[image]

Which basically is a grid, with the lat/long coordinates of the 4 corners.

**The Problem**

I need to find for every row in A, which (non-unique) row it is bounded by in B. As in, the gps coordinates are inside the box as described by the row in B. I have a function that returns `True/False` when given the coords from A and the row in B.

Right now I'm doing a bruteforce approach, iterating through the whole B dataframe and checking every row if it belongs to that box or not. However, this is incredibly inefficient and very slow.

I'm sure there must be a better way for this, as it's a common problem. Can anyone point me to them?

Thank you! :)

Edit:

Code for the function im using to find if a particular gps_coord belongs in the box defined by a row

```
import matplotlib.path as path
def find_if_point_in_bounding_box(row,gps_coords):
    top_left_lat = row['top_left_lat']
    top_left_long = row['top_left_long']
    top_right_lat = row['top_right_lat']
    top_right_long = row['top_right_long']
    bottom_left_lat = row['bottom_left_lat']
    bottom_left_long = row['bottom_left_long']
    bottom_right_lat = row['bottom_right_lat']
    bottom_right_long = row['bottom_right_long']

    lat,long = gps_coords
     # create box
    p = path.Path([(top_left_lat, top_left_long),(top_right_lat,top_right_long),(bottom_left_lat,bottom_left_long),(bottom_right_lat,bottom_right_long)])
    res = p.contains_points([(lat,long)])[0]
    return res
```

Comment: Why the redundancy? A box can be defined by the top left and bottom right coordinates. The `top_right_lat` and `bottorm_right_lat` are always going to be the same value, etc.

Comment: @VictorRuiz: that's not very helpful. GeoPandas can handle any of this just fine.

Comment: How are you currently handling the anti-meridian? Put differently, do you have any bounding boxes that straddle the international dateline (`*_left_lon > 0` and `*_right_lon < 0`)?

Comment: Didnt know about GeoPandas. But im sure using a database and a query is better than iterating each row of data to search for those that meet some condition (if such condition can be expressed as a query). But you can share how to do it with GeoPandas

Comment: @VictorRuiz: and note that Pandas provide indexes just like a database does. These are not simple lists to be scanned sequentially.

Comment: And the columns data are kept on memory or disk?

Comment: @VictorRuiz: in memory. "Over a million rows" is not actually that big a dataframe.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No this is within a small area, so anti-meridian isnt a worry. Geopandas is interesting, but correct me if im misunderstanding this, it doesnt really help this problem, yes?

Comment: @Marijn Pieters Okay, i read "billions"

Comment: @Wboy: I don't actually think we need geopandas here (and the underlying Shapely geometry types don't handle anti-meridian-crossing polygons correctly).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm already using shapely for the "finding if a particular gps coord is belongs to a particular box" function

Comment: @Wboy: sure, but converting a million rows to a geopandas dataframe is [going to take a few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820969/python-geo-spatial-coordinate-format-conversion/56876903#56876903) and I'm not sure it is worth it here.

Comment: @Wboy: besides, I don't think the GeoSeries index supports bounding box containment tests. If it supported [prepared geometry operations](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#prepared-geometry-operations) directly on the index, then that'd be awesome, but I can't find any evidence in the docs or source code that it does.

Comment: Your `find_if_point_in_bounding_box()` function doesn't test for a bounding box. It tests if your `lat,long` pairs fall inside an **hourglass**. Moreover, your left the path open. `matplotlib.path.Path()` is not the best type to use for boundary box testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 8 coordinates contain only 4 unique values each: 2 latitudes (forming the top and bottom boundaries of each box, or the northerly and southerly bounds) and two longitudes (the left and right boundaries, westerly and easterly). Between the 4 (lat, lon) combinations for the 4 corners you’ll see that there are repeated values. You only need to compare your positions with the 4 boundaries, the latitude should fall between (or on) the two latitude bounds, and the longitude should fall between the two longitude bounds.

So you can simply ask for rows that have matching bounding boxes based on one each of `top_*_lat` and  `bottom_*_lat` for the latitude, and one each of `*_left_long` and `*_right_long` for the longitudes:

```
lat, long = <latitude>, <longitude>
matching_rows = df.query(
    # top and bottom latitudes, top lat > bottom lat, north to south
    "top_left_lat >= @lat >= bottom_right_lat and "
    # left and right longitudes, left long < right long, west to east
    "top_left_long <= @long <= bottom_right_long"
)
```

The above [`pandas.DataFrame.query()` expression](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) just does a simple geometric point containment test and assumes that your bounding boxes do not cross the anti-meridian (international dateline) nor overlap with either pole.

You'll have to do this for each position in your input dataframe; Pandas can't merge dataframes based on arbitrary expressions (yet). You could group your inputs by one of the two coordinates to produce a subset of rows that match that one coordinate, then further filter them on the second coordinate for each group.

If your input dataframe is also very large, then it may perhaps be better to use a database for such a join.

Comment: Hey Martijin, thanks for your reply! That's pretty genius querying the coordinates like that. I tested the query, but the results dont seem to agree with the box function. every result from `[find_if_point_in_bounding_box(matching_rows.loc[i],(lat,lon)) for i in matching_rows.index]` returns False.. I've added the code for find_if_ etc in the question if needed

Comment: @Wboy: your function is wrong, I'm afraid. You defined a Z path.

Comment: @Wboy: sorry, I assumed this was a different `Path` object. You appear to be using *matplotlib*'s path? Then you are testing for containment in an hourglass shape. You mixed up your bottom coordinates.

Comment: Wait.. what. Really? so its `p = path.Path([(top_left_lat, top_left_long),(top_right_lat,top_right_long),(bottom_right_lat,bottom_right_long),bottom_left_lat,bottom_left_long)])`?

Comment: I tried the above and reran a test case, again it shows all False though. I manually checked using https://www.mapcustomizer.com/# and using 28.617771 77.2225269 as the input test case. The first row of `matching_rows` gives the following coords for the box: `28.619513,77.224254` `28.619513,77.226280` `28.617732,77.226280` `28.617732,77.224254` but if you plot it, you'll see that its not inside the box

Comment: @Wboy I spotted and corrected an error in the last condition.

Comment: @Martijin that still didn't work, what worked was `matching_rows = traffic.query("top_left_lat >= @lat & ""bottom_right_lat <= @lat & ""top_left_long >= @lon & ""bottom_right_long >= @lon")`,  is this what you meant? I'll go ahead and mark your answer as correct first since it did help and im grateful!

Comment: @Wboy: no, that query specifically **excludes** your longitude boundaries. The query only matches of your longitude is greater than or equal to both to left and the right longitude.... that can only be true if the point is to the east of the boundary box, not inside it.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the saving of the coordinates, my bottom 2 coordinates were flipped. But still your given code doesnt seem to work, but this works so far on 3 test cases that ive tried : `"top_left_lat >= @lat & "top_left_long <= @lon & bottom_right_lat <= @lat & bottom_right_long >= @lon"`

Comment: @Wboy that’s essentially the same query I gave you already. I’ve updated the query to use chained comparisons (I confirmed that Pandas supports those), and expanded the explanation as to how this works.

Comment: @Wboy: right, I figured out where I went wrong with the query: I assumed that latitude top > bottom (from north to south) and longitude left > right (from east to west). But that's not actually the case, of course, longitudes generally increase from west to east instead, when using GPS / WGS 84.